# inputs for nDCG in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ranking, xgboost

I'm unable to understand the input format of sklearn nDcg: http://sklearn.apachecn.org/en/0.19.0/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ndcg_score.html

Currently I have the following problem: I have multiple queries for each of which the ranking probabilities have been calculated successfully. But now the problem is calculating nDCG for the test set for which I would like to use the sklearn nDcg. The example given on the link

```
>>> y_true = [1, 0, 2]
>>> y_score = [[0.15, 0.55, 0.2], [0.7, 0.2, 0.1], [0.06, 0.04, 0.9]]
>>> ndcg_score(y_true, y_score, k=2)
1.0
```

According to site, y_true is ground truth and y_score are the probabilities.So following are my questions:

1. Is this example for just one query or multiple queries?
2. If this is for just one query then what does y_true represents: original rankings?
3. If this is for a single query and why we have multiple input probabilites?
4. How this method can be applied to multiple queries and their resultant probabilites?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9921#issuecomment-336777461

Answer (score 6):

You can look at it similar to a multiclass classification problem.

So to answer your question

> 1. Is this example for just one query or multiple queries?

One query

> 2. If this is for just one query then what does y_true represents: original rankings?

I would refer to it as the relevancy label for the documents as it may have duplicate values.

> 3. If this is for a single query and why we have multiple input probabilites?

`y_score` is the probability distribution of the document belonging to a certain class. In your example `y_score = [[0.15, 0.55, 0.2], [0.7, 0.2, 0.1], [0.06, 0.04, 0.9]]` means the 0th document belongs to class 1 (0.55 is the max), the 1st document belongs to class 0 (0.7 is the max) and the 2nd document belongs to class 2 (0.9 is the max). The documentation is lacking and the example is misleading as well. It would be better if there were four documents.

> 4. How this method can be applied to multiple queries and their resultant probabilites?

You can then average the nDCG scores for each query across multiple queries.